# How to delete all your old website data from the internet?

Tags: google-search-console, redirects, 404

I had my website on `rohbits.com` but for some reasons I had to delete it and recreate it with this URL `wwww.rohbits.com/blog`. My problem is that the old links are still visible on google search and when people click on those links, they land on a 404 Error page of the hosting company. I want to either delete all the previous data from the search engines or have an 404 Error page of my own so that I can tell my visitors where the actual website is.

I have already redirected all the traffic which comes to `rohbits.com` to `www.rohbits.com/blog` but when they click on the expired links, they get this error page.

One sample expired link is this one: http://rohbits.com/wordpress-tricks.

Comment: You say you've already redirected "all the traffic", but seemingly not "wordpress-tricks"(?) - is this because this page simply does not exist at all, even in the new location?

Comment: @w3d I had to delete those post and I don't have the wordpress tricks post in the new blog. That's why i want it to removed out of the search engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly not a case for deleting content, instead you should make sure the redirection works correctly. With redirecting you would not only keep your reputation, old links would also show the new content without error pages between.

I don't know what you already did to redirect your pages, but in most cases you can write a **.htaccess** file and place it in the root folder of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rohbits.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.rohbits.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This example is is not tested, but hopefully it should get you started. More information about redirecting you can find [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html). Of course the same pages should be available in the new blog directory.

Should you have changed the entire page structure, then don't use the `$1`, and make sure that a generic page is available at the given address.

Comment: I am using redirection tool available in the cPanel. It redirects all the traffic coming to http://rohbits.com but if I even type this http://rohbits.com/test, it will land on the default hosting 404 error page. I have seen some blogs like http://hongkiat.com in which all the traffic get directed to www.hongkiat.com/blog and even if you type hongkiat.com/wowo/wowo, it will still redirect you to www.hongkiat.com/blog. I don;t know how they do it.

Comment: @AkkyAwesøme - Probably you see this error page, because no file can be found at URL _rohbits.com/test_ . I think hongkiat wrote a `.htaccess` file as in the example above. With the `$1` it would redirect _rohbits.com/test_ to _www.rohbits.com/blog/test_, without the `$1` it would redirect all urls to _www.rohbits.com/blog/_ . Did it actually solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

***To completely remove an entire page***

On the Webmaster Tools home page, click the site you want.

On the Dashboard, click **Google Index** on the left-hand menu.

Click **Remove URLs**.

Click **New removal request**.

Type the URL of the page you want removed from search results (not the Google search results URL or cached page URL), and then click **Continue**. How to find the right URL. The URL is case-sensitive—use exactly the same characters and capitalization that the site uses.

Click **Yes, remove this page**.

Click **Submit Request**.

***To remove the cached version of a page***

On the Webmaster Tools home page, click the site you want.

On the left-hand menu, click **Google Index** and then click **Remove** **URLs**.

Click **New removal request**.

Type the URL of the page you want removed, and then click Continue. The URL is case-sensitive—use exactly the same characters and capitalization that the site uses. How to find the right URL.

Select **Remove cached version of this page**.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped but still the redirection problem exists as it did before.

Answer (score 0):

Removing URL's from google's index is not a good idea.You should redirect your old URLS to the new URLS with HTTP 301 code else your search engine rankings will drop . Also make sure that you canonicalize the new URLS.